# Mongodb import json with _id

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport

I am trying to import the following data in a mongodb collection

```
[
{"_id":NumberLong(1), "name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"},
{"_id":NumberLong(2), "name": "Aland Islands", "code": "AX"},
{"_id":NumberLong(3), "name": "Albania", "code": "AL"},
{"_id":NumberLong(4), "name": "Algeria", "code": "DZ"},
{"_id":NumberLong(5), "name": "American Samoa", "code": "AS"},
{"_id":NumberLong(6), "name": "AndorrA", "code": "AD"}
]
```

I am getting errors -

```
D:\mongodb\bin>mongoimport --db mopi --collection somecountry --type json --file
 somecountry.json --jsonArray
connected to: 127.0.0.1
Fri Nov 07 14:20:45.149 exception:BSON representation of supplied JSON array is
too large: code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: Bad characters in value: offset:7
Fri Nov 07 14:20:45.151 [
{"_id":NumberLong(1), "name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"},
{"_id":NumberLong(2), "name": "Aland Islands", "code": "AX"},
{"_id":NumberLong(3), "name": "Albania", "code": "AL"},
{"_id":NumberLong(4), "name": "Algeria", "code": "DZ"},
{"_id":NumberLong(5), "name": "American Samoa", "code": "AS"},
{"_id":NumberLong(6), "name": "AndorrA", "code": "AD"}
]

Fri Nov 07 14:20:45.152 check 0 0
Fri Nov 07 14:20:45.153 imported 0 objects
Fri Nov 07 14:20:45.153 ERROR: encountered 1 error(s)
```

Comment: Try using mongoimport without --type json. That might work.

Comment: Still getting same errors.

Comment: which MongoDB version you used? I tried same above it work fine in Mongo version 2.6.4.

Comment: mongoimport will work, but only when the "types" are formatted properly as in [extended json](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) what you have will only evaluate in the mongo shell. So the export is wrong.

Comment: @NeilLunn just wanted to understand how to format this in extended json format?

Comment: More to point is "how is this exported?" because what I am saying is you are "doing it wrong"

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are showing us an abbreviation of your data. The error says that the BSON resulting from your JSON exceeds the hard 16MB limit. You can fix the problem by reformatting the data. Instead of putting multiple documents in an array and importing with --jsonArray, which restricts the total import size to 16MB, put one json document per line:

```
{"_id":NumberLong(1), "name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"},
{"_id":NumberLong(2), "name": "Aland Islands", "code": "AX"},
{"_id":NumberLong(3), "name": "Albania", "code": "AL"},
{"_id":NumberLong(4), "name": "Algeria", "code": "DZ"},
{"_id":NumberLong(5), "name": "American Samoa", "code": "AS"},
{"_id":NumberLong(6), "name": "AndorrA", "code": "AD"}
...
```